# How to get the Target of a lamdba Action?

Tags: c#, lambda, casting, delegates

I tried to cast a delegate.Target to a class I wrote, let's just name it `MyClass`.

When I tried to cast it with `(MyClass)del.Target`, it told me `Specified cast is not valid`.

When I debug it, I found out that it's some kind of `DisplayClass` object, and I found an `f` member in it through the Watch Window, and the cast will be successful with `(MyClass)del.Target.f.Target`.

But when I got out of the debug mode, the `f` member does NOT exist in the `Target` any more.

How can I cast it properly?

### Update

I figure out where that `f` comes from: It's an anonymous function that I used in a `foreach` loop where I populate the `del`.

And `del` is a lambda expression instead of an instance.

This is what parts of the codes look like (simplified):

```
List<Action<int>> Outputs = new List<Action<int>>();
List<Action<int>> Inputs;  //Please assume that this is already been populated from somewhere else.

foreach(Action<int> f in Inputs)  //This is where the `f` member came from
{
    Outputs.Add((a) => f(3));
}

foreach(Action<int> del in Outputs)
{
    MyClass mc = (MyClass)del.Target;  //This is where the cast failed.
}
```

Now it makes sense why `(MyClass)del.Target.f.Target` will succeed in debug mode.

So now the problem becomes, "How could I get the function delegate before it is generated by the compiler?"

Comment: Kind of weird that you would want to do this. `DisplayClass` means that it's an anonymous lambda. Please show relevant code

Comment: @Charlieface Updated, please be so kind as to take a look.

Comment: Why do you *want* to cast it? What do you want to do with it that you need to cast it? The reason this worked in debug is that in debug it is compiled into an instance function (with a `this`), but in release that is optimized away and it becomes a `static` function, therefore there is no target object.

Comment: @Charlieface Because there is something in `MyClass` I need to access. So there is no way to cast this?

Comment: No, it simply doesn't refer to the same object. Because you have a captured variable `f` it creates a temporary object to put it in. I suggest you find a way of storing `MyClass` with the lambda.

Comment: @Charlieface Ah, OK, thank you very much, I'll think of another way to do it.